# Regex Pattern for form field "- word word"

Tags: regex, forms

Hello I have need of a regex pattern for a text field that only accepts input that starts with a hyphen followed by a space and then words.

For example:

```
- San Diego
- Rolando
```

I've tried `^[-]\ \w+` but that doesn't work. Please help.

Answer (score 1):

You may use

```
^-( \w+)+$
```

Or a version with a non-capturing group: `^-(?: \w+)+$`. If any whitespace is meant, replace the space with `\s`. See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/4Jz26w/1).

**Details**:

- `^`  - start of string
- `-` - a hyphen
- `( \w+)+` - 1 or more sequences of:

  - - space
  - `\w+` - 1 or more letters, digits or underscores
- `$` - end of string

Answer (score 0):

You can also use this one [`^(?:-[\w ]+)+$`](https://regex101.com/r/HXLy4N/4)

- `- [\w ]+` matches an hyphen and a space followed by any number of word character or space
- `(?:...)+` matches the content one or more times
- `^` and `$` matches start and end of string respectively

Comment: This will also validate `-name`. There must be a space between `-` and the word, and also, hyphen is only allowed at the start of the string.